# Why is my hard drive still working long after I finished the file transfer?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I noticed that every time I copy a large amount of data to my hard drive, it is still working after the file transfer is over. It makes some sounds as if it were still being written on, as if it were defragmenting.

Now it is placed on a Linux server with Raspberry Pi, but also before, when we connected it to the laptop with Windows, it did the same thing. And I didn't have any defragmentation program activated... The bigger the amount of data, the longer it takes until it stops working at... god knows what. It is a WD Blue 1TB connected to USB 3.0. It has EXT4 partition under Linux and had NTFS too before.

What do you think it is? Should I get worried?

Comment: Could be some OS related file indexing.

Comment: Are you seeing the *drive* doing work (e.g., a status light on the drive enclosure)? Or are you seeing *traffic* (e.g., a status light on the USB connection)? The drive could be SMR (as described very well in an answer). The connection would be an OS related issue (e.g., flushing a write cache).

Comment: It doesn't have a led. I just hear it doing sound like it is working to read or write something...

Comment: For how long do these drive sounds continue after the transfer has completed? That may be relevant for answering the question.

Comment: About 30 minutes... after I write hundreds of GB.

Comment: Ah, in that case it won't be the OS flushing write caches. Mokubai's SMR theory seems very plausible.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Depending on the specific model of drive it may be using SMR technology. [Shingled Magnetic Recording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingled_magnetic_recording) is a technology that can increase the density of data written and make more effective use of the physical space on the drive but it has a couple of costs.

- Due to the overlapping of data the writing of data to the SMR area of the drive is actually slower and more difficult to write. It can only be written in strips rather than randomly like a CMR drive.
- as the SMR area is slower many SMR drives have a more conventional "old style" CMR/PMR zone which they use to cache incoming writes before being copied to the SMR zone by the disk controller.

The net result is the behaviour you see. The drive accepts data seemingly normally and then spends some time afterwards rearranging data on the disk as it copies the data from the CMR zone to the SMR zone.

Half an hour seems excessive, but it could be moving the data in small packets over time to keep the drive interface available for use.

NASCompares has a list of drives and whether they use normal CMR or SMR technology at [List of WD CMR and SMR hard drives (HDD)](https://nascompares.com/answer/list-of-wd-cmr-and-smr-hard-drives-hdd/). You can filter the list by make, model and so on to find your specific drive.

I have seen some drives that literally look like they have died during writing. They accept several GB of data and then writes drop to zero for some period of time while the drive reorganises data to clear the CMR zone. After the drive has freed up the "cache" then it carries on writing but for a period of time measured in minutes the drive is as good as unusable.

As long as you are aware that you have one of these drives it is not a problem, but if you *don't* know then it can look a lot like the drive is defective or doing something very odd.

Comment: I checked the list, it's SMR ! :( WD Blue 1TB WD10SPZX

Comment: And that's why SMR drives are ok if you write an office document every half hour, but nothing much else. And if you use your PC for nothing much else than writing office documents every half hour, the "advantage" of SMR drives, providing more disk space on less physical space, isn't even needed.

Comment: @MarusGradinaru While SMR drives are a bit odd at least you know that what is happening is vaguely normal. Personally I'd consider these kinds of drives most useful for primarily occasional writing with lots of reading, but they can be used for most things as long as you are aware of some quirks when writing a lot of data. Manufacturers should absolutely be upfront about the differences in how particular models work but it's not the end of the world to actually use one. Some manufacturers could also do with working on their drive firmware to not make it look like the drive is defective.

Comment: There is no sane reason (other than flawed metrics like GB/$) to buy a SMR disk.

Comment: There was quite a bit of controversy a while ago about hard drive manufacturers not labeling their drives as SMR https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/04/caveat-emptor-smr-disks-are-being-submarined-into-unexpected-channels/

Comment: @fraxinus I kinda agree. Realistically you shouldn't willingly buy an SMR disk unless you are getting a stupidly good deal, and with SSDs consistently getting cheaper there are less and less reasons to buy spinning rust except for massive (10+TB) drives, and even then you'd prefer a CMR/PMR disk if you can get it.

Comment: "As long as you are aware that you have one of these drives it is not a problem"  Oh, you have a problem all right, just a _different_ one than we're talking about here.

Comment: @fraxinus There are perfectly fine use cases for SMR drives ("archiving" data being the obvious one - SMR drives work fine for bulk sequential writes and then mostly reading data; not only for personal use - eg dropbox [is using a lot of them just fine](https://dropbox.tech/infrastructure/smr-what-we-learned-in-our-first-year)), the problem isn't the tech by itself, but the deceptive actions of some manufacturers (it's hard to keep track of which ones are still honest at this point though).

Comment: @Voo Really? As long as you are OK with ~50MB/s bulk sequential write speed in 2022, sure. And this is an average speed only, because you get few seconds interruptions once in a while. And no matter what you do, the disk becomes internally fragmented and you get a bunch of a seek delays even when reading a single, non-fragmented (in the LBA sense) file.

Comment: @Fraxinus So if I write a few TB of pictures and video files to the disk and then only read those (in the unlikely case that I need one of my backup disks) , it will become internally fragmented? Rather unlikely, at least I haven't experienced that. By the same argument you could also argue against PMR disks, because SSDs are much faster. As with most technical things there are lots of factors that influence the final decision

Comment: Absolutely off-topic, but "Shingled Magnetic Recording" seems like some sort of disease that a robot would get. What a weirdly named tech!

Comment: @T.Sar do robots get innoculated against shingled magnetic recordings?

Comment: From the Dropbox post @Voo linked to: "_We’re able to store roughly 10 to 20 percent more data on an SMR drive than on a PMR drive of the same capacity at little to no cost difference._"  o.O ...Clearly, Dropbox have some new definition of "capacity" I'm not familiar with. (And "cost", for that matter, since SMR drives "of the same capacity" SHOULDN'T cost the same — the entire point of the exercise was, they're supposed to be way cheaper! Even if we assume that's _net_ cost... if Dropbox really went to all that effort **just** to break even, I imagine management is pretty pissed.)

Comment: @FeRD The new bare metal software approach seems to have a much lower overhead than traditional file systems (not surprisingly). That would presumably also work with PMR drives, but you still get the energy and hardware cost savings from the SMR drives which are separate to that.

Comment: @Voo Are they separate, though? I was only half-joking about the 'definition of "cost"' thing. They never define how they're measuring their costs. If it's flat purchase price, then a storage rack that's _"resulted in more than a 20% percent savings overall compared to the last generation storage design"_ while **also** increasing capacity and lowering power consumption is pretty good. But if it's net dollars per gigabyte stored, then all that other stuff is factored in already, and it's a pretty abysmal savings when you consider the economies of scale involved.

Comment: @Fred I don't see why you'd doubt the engineers. The fact that cheaper drives with larger capacity (storage density is very important in data centers) and less power usage would be a net gain for a company that does to a large part archival storage seems pretty clear cut as long as you can optimize your software stack to hit your performance goals. But if you're that interested in details, I'm sure you can contact one of the engineers - there's usually someone enthusiastic about these topics in my experience.

Answer (score 4):

Default Linux behavior is to cache in RAM. As a result the *Read* can finish much sooner than the *Write*. Depending upon sizes and speeds of the devices this difference can be quite large, especially with a lot of RAM available.

I'm not sure why "*Complete*" is announced based upon the read but you need to take care to allow the write to finish before removing the drive.

Another possibility is related to relative ***Block Sizes***. If your *Read* device has a gazillion tiny files with a small block size and you *Write* device has a large block size, you can completely overwhelm the *Write* device writing tiny files that take up large blocks.

Comment: I have only 4GB of RAM and the "extra work" continues about 30 minutes after I finished the transfer... I don't think it's cache related...

Comment: One can run the `sync` command to make sure all write buffers have been flushed. But most file managers take this into account in their file copy progress windows.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if there are filesystem enhancements/flags that could help mitigate the issues here? Linux ext4 is rather well-known as being far less fragmentation-prone than NTFS, because it too rearranges blocks on the fly when writing file data, and decouples metadata writes (to the journal) from file block writes. But that could worsen things with SMR, especially in the default layout where every write involves *both* journal writes and filesystem block updates, in completely separate areas of the disk.

Kernel dev Ted Ts'o and others looked into this [way back in 2017](https://lwn.net/Articles/720226/), and came up with an "ext4-lazy" variation on the standard filesystem implementation that avoided triggering a lot of SMR's worst behaviors. Unfortunately, it looks like those patches never made it into the kernel, and as it's been four years I wouldn't hold out much hope that they will.

But, still, their work pointed to some adjustments to the *current* ext4 implementation that might benefit you some:

- You could try growing the journal to the maximum allowable size, 40GB with 4K blocks. (It's 10,240,000 blocks max, so 10GB with 1K blocks.) You'd do that with `tune2fs -J size=40000 /dev/foo`. Ts'o's research showed that using a large journal as a write cache was a significant improvement.
- Coupled with the previous, you could turn on eager data journaling with `tune2fs -o journal_data /dev/foo`, so that "all data (not  just  metadata) is committed into  the journal prior  to being written into the main file system."
- For the absolute maximum bang for your buck, you could move the filesystem's journal to a *separate device entirely* (one that's not SMR), so that writes to the SMR disk only happen for data blocks and only to the area where the data is stored. You'd do that by formatting a journal device on another drive using `mke2fs -O journal_dev /dev/bar`. "Note that [/dev/bar] must be formatted with the same block size as file systems which will be
  using it." then you'd set that device as the journal for `/dev/foo` using `tune2fs -J device=/dev/bar /dev/foo`.

If you're going to do the latter, forget about the first suggestion, as the size of the journal will just be the size of `/dev/bar`. (Though I suspect it still won't use any more than 40GB, so on the bright side you don't need a big journal disk!) Needless to say, it's probably safest to try making any of these adjustments only after first unmounting the filesystem in question, and even though I'm pretty sure `tune2fs` would balk if asked to do anything destructive, for maximum safety it's a good idea to take a backup, or at least experiment on a throwaway filesystem first.